# How to open a native iOS app from a web app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I can open a native iOS app from a web app with the iOS 8.1,iOS 7 and iOS 6,but in iOS 8.2 it's doesn't work!
Here is My HTML Code:

```
var sdkurl = 'MyAppName:paramsName=MTA1MzEwMDAwNjMwMDA';
sdkurl = encodeURI(sdkurl);
window.location = sdkurl;
```

Anybody can help?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you register for the URL scheme in the app's info.plist file as well as implement the appdelegate method `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: `?

Comment: yes,i did that,only in iOS8.2 it's doesn't work ,that's really confused.

Comment: thanks, i've found the problem,i did't click trust the app.